# How to $push all of the document in aggregation instead of specific field

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have this array of results in the first stage of the aggregation pipeline, using a `$match`:

```
[
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 }
]
```

Now I want to sum all of the A's and B's and also still have them so I will have something like this as a result:

```
{
  total_sum: 10,
  items: [...] // first and second objects ofcourse
}
```

I have tried to `$group` and `$push`, however, push only pushes specific fields from the object and I need to name A and B, instead just of parsing all of them.

How can I do it?

Comment: Is this what you try to achieve? [Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mtvZuSxcVa5). Just not understand what do you mean `I need to name A and B, instead just of parse all of them.`.

Comment: Yes I just looked for this `$$ROOT`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `$set` - Create new field `total` to sum `a` and `b`.
2. `$group` - Group by `null`, indicate to sum all `total` and add the document in `items` array.

With `$$ROOT` it will add the whole document.

```
items: {
  $push: "$ROOT"
}
```

If you want just some fields only, then specify the (desired) document pattern.

```
items: {
  $push: {
    A: "$a",
    B: "$b"
  }
}
```

3. `$unset` (If use `$push $$ROOT`) - Remove `total` field from `items` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      total: {
        $sum: [
          "$a",
          "$b"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total_sum: {
        $sum: "$total"
      },
      items: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "items.total"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tz7d77zp72z)